# VBA quick way to paint thousands of cells from array of addresses

Tags: vba, excel, performance

I have a sheet with ~300 lines and 30 columns of numbers. I need to paint cells as a result of processing `SelectionChange` event. Performance is imporant as issue of usability.

**First way** is to take a `Range` object for every cell I'm going to highlight:

```
For x = 1 To 30: For y = 1 To lastNonemptyRow
    If someClause(CInt(Cells(rowIdx, colIdx).Value)) Then
        Range(Cells(rowIdx, colIdx).Value).Interior.Color = Rgb(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next y: Next x
```

This way is quite slow even with disabled `ScreenUpdating`.

**Second way** is to make a string with set of addresses:

```
addressesToHighlight = ""
For x = 1 To 30: For y = 1 To lastNonemptyRow
    If someClause(CInt(Cells(rowIdx, colIdx).Value)) Then
        addressesToHighlight = addressesToHighlight & Cells(rowIdx, colIdx).Address & ", "
    End If
Next y: Next x
Range(addressesToHighlight).Interior.Color = Rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

This way gives error when there is 42 or more cells to highlight.

**Third way** is to create a range as union of two ranges which are previously accumulated cells and current cell:

```
Set resultRange = Nothing
For x = 1 To 30: For y = 1 To lastNonemptyRow
    If someClause(CInt(Cells(rowIdx, colIdx).Value)) Then
        If resultRange is Nothing then
            Set resultRange = Range(Cells(rowIdx, colIdx))
        Else
            Set resultRange = Union(resultRange, Range(Cells(rowIdx, colIdx)))
        End if
    End If
Next y: Next x
resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

This way is quite fast but after 1000 cells its execution time grows exponentially: 1000 cells are highlighted in 1.5 sec, 2000 cells are highlighted in 8 sec.

What is the fastest way to specify and highlight arbitrary 1000..10000 cells?

Comment: Are you just highlighting the cells and is there no real content in them? If so, write values to your array that would denote the colour e.g. 1 is green, 2 is red etc. Then use conditional formatting to colour all the cells and the text. You can create your config in an array very quickly. Write back to all your cells in one hit and then conditional formatting will take care of the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of what you are looking to do. Without further information re what sort of clause you would use I had to come up with own puzzle  I employee many (all?) of the techniques used to speed up programs. 10 executes had average runtime of .2254 seconds with 10k cells painted

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function timeGetTime Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long

Sub newnew()
Dim started As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim paintRng As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim arrRng() As Variant
Dim wsTwo As Worksheet
Dim rngTwo As Range
Dim colNum As Long
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim ended As Long

    started = timeGetTime

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    started = timeGetTime

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    paintRng = "A1:J1000"

    Set rng = ws.Range(paintRng)
    ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count
    RowCount = rng.Rows.Count

    ReDim arrRng(1 To RowCount, 1 To ColumnCount)
    arrRng = rng

    Debug.Print ColumnCount
    Debug.Print RowCount


    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing

    Set wsTwo = Sheets("Sheet2")
    wsTwo.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Set rngTwo = wsTwo.Range(paintRng)

    With rngTwo
        For colNum = 1 To ColumnCount
            For rowNum = 1 To RowCount
                If arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 1 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 2 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(125, 0, 0)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 3 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 4 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 5 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(125, 125, 0)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 6 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(125, 0, 125)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 7 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(75, 75, 200)
                ElseIf arrRng(rowNum, colNum) = 8 Then
                    .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Interior.Color = RGB(50, 125, 255)
                End If
            Next rowNum
        Next colNum
    End With

    Set wsTwo = Nothing
    Set rngTwo = Nothing

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    ended = timeGetTime
    Debug.Print ColumnCount * RowCount & " Cells Painted In " & (ended - started) / 1000 & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Your way is more useful because I need to use different colors. Looks like it works fast on 12K cells. Maybe Range(...) call is really expensive.

Comment: I just wonder, why there are `With...End With` in every Case? Isn't it better just use `cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)` or move `With cell` before `For...Each`?

Comment: The same goes for `wsTwo`. You're using `With...End With` to set page break, but why you didn't do same thing for `rngtwo`?

Comment: could not place the with cell outside of for loop, but you are right the with statements just added extra steps, cell.interior.color was faster. i am not sure what you mean by setting rngtwo pagebreak = false, no such option exists. explain? also i switched from select to if else statements which are faster. thank you for feedback.